# what are iwlwifi_1-virtual-0 and pch_cannonlake-virtual-0 in sensors output in linux?

Tags: sensors, lm-sensors

this is my `sensors` output:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +42.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +40.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +41.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +63.0°C  

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +62.0°C
```

I can see that both `iwlwifi_1-virtual-0` and `pch_cannonlake-virtual-0` are pretty **high** temperature with `63.0°C` and `62.0°C`. Should I pay atention on these two devices? What are they? Does the temperature mean anything?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

`iwlwifi_1-virtual-0` is the wireless adapter and `pch_cannonlake-virtual-0` is the [platform control hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub). PCHs tend to run hotter than CPUs. According to [these](https://forums.aida64.com/topic/1128-pch-diode-what-temperature-it-is-normal/?do=findComment&comment=6477) [threads](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/629235-the-heck-is-a-pch-and-why-is-it-so-hot/?do=findComment&comment=8127416) issues don't occur until you exceed around 80C, so at 62C that seems fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have upvoted it. Do you know why they are called **Virtual** devices? I am confused because I thought they were something virtual and not real due to the word **Virtual**. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

"iwlwifi_1-virtual-0" refers to a small M.2 form factor Intel wireless module (card) which should be replaceable. If you look on the back of your motherboard, there is a silver rectangular box where the wifi antennas connect to. This houses the physical wireless module inside, it is not a virtual device. On some boards the wifi card is exposed visibly.

To answer your question directly, the operating temperatures for those Intel wifi cards are rated up to 80C. 63C is fine. There isn't much you can do to decrease temperatures since the module is housed within the metal shroud so it's not like your case cooling is inadequate or whatever. It's just how the manufacturer designed it and as we well know, they don't always take into account these little concerns about specific component temperatures.

The wifi cards are replaceable if you do happen to burn it out for like $5-$20, so I honestly would not worry about it. There should be two screws holding the casing together on the bottom of the motherboard to take that whole assembly apart. Some motherboard BIOSes are weird and lock out using other wifi cards other than directly the original model, so be wary of that as well.