# WiFi sensor temperature increases when disabling wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, temperature, wifi-configuration, networkmanager, sensors

For some strange reason, when I disable wifi with the nmcli command

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

I see an immediate rise in the wifi sensor temperature, from around 30C to more than 60C. Because of this, I leave WiFi always active. Fedora 38 fully updated here.

This happens with a Dell Optiplex7000 SSF. Yet, with a Dell Optiplex7000 Micro this problem does not occur.

Why is this happening, and how to prevent it?

**EDIT**

I relied my question on the output of gkrellm sensor plugin, the sensor it calls `iwlwifi_1@0/temp1` (no idea which command/library it uses). I then installed `lm_sensors`, which reports (WiFi ON):

```
...
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +30.0°C 
...
```

Then, after turning off WiFi, `lm_sensors` reports:

```
...
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:         N/A
...
```

So it seems @Mokubai is right, and there is some invalid data that gkrellm is picking that `lm_sensors` is not. Specially taking into account that the other sensors remain around the same values, and the new temperature agrees with the Ambient one.

Comment: You should edit your question to specify what exactly is your question

Comment: Could it be a false reading from the sensor? Though the only way to check I can imagine is to open the case to measure with an IR thermometer.

Comment: I looked on 3 machines and the wireless card for the machine does not have a temperature sensor.  Can you add Advanced Properties (Device Manager) to your question?

Comment: Could simply be that with the Wifi chip switched off the driver attempts to read whatever sensor is in it and gets back invalid data, potentially all 1's, and maximum range for the temperature sensor corresponds to "more than 60C".

Comment: To everyone who answer, please see my EDIT. To @John, please see https://superuser.com/a/1564372/305679